Use CSS zoom to fix website to design width
I have a well designed, responsive site, that looks great on almost any screen. It's got all the media breaks to look good on smaller devices, even mobile. Great!
Most designers are worried about how their site looks on mobile and smaller devices.... but the other day I looked at my site on a massively high resolution screen. Look, all websites look terrible, all squashed up in the middle or to the left where "the end of the designer would have imagined any screen to be".
I had a max-width css set to the body tag, and that helped hold things together, but what I noticed is that by simply applying a zoom to the same body tag, I could get this ridiculously large screen resolution to display my site quite nicely.
I would like to know how I could set a zoom value to apply to the css if the body width becomes really wide.
So far I have:
@media (min-width: 2560px) {
    body{
        zoom: 120%;
    }
 }

But I want this value to be calculated, so something like:
zoom: calc(1 + 2560 / var(--width));
But how do I get --width to be the available media width?
The end result would display my site exactly as my designer wanted it, even at a very high resolution.

Quick Solution - zoom & window.innerWidth
If you need an answer that deals with absolute pixel values and zoom, you could use some JS to procedurally set --width's value on :root.
You'd first need to define te @property in css, and then set it with js.
Note that i've used :root as it provides a more general solution, that makes --width available to any css selector. If you only need the body to adjust, you could modify the js snippet to set the property on body instead.


function adjustWidthVar(){
  const root = document.querySelector(':root');
  root.style.setProperty('--windowWidth', window.innerWidth);
}

adjustWidthVar(); // call on script load;
window.onresize = adjustWidthVar; //call everytime the window resizes
@property --windowWidth{
    syntax: '<number>'; /*asume everything is on pixels*/
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0; 
}
@media and (min-width: 1024px){ /*SOME_PIXEL_VALUE*/
    div.design{
        --designWidth : 1024; /*SAME_PIXEL_VALUE_AS_QUERY*/
        zoom: calc(var(--windowWidth) / var(--designWidth));
    }
}
<html>
<body>
<div class=design>Your Design Here</div>
</body>
</html>



More 'idiomatic' solution - Viewport Units
The CSS standard conveniently includes relative lenght units, in particular:

vh and vw are relative to the viewport's height and width, respectively.

As stated on MDN:

The benefit of using relative units is that with some careful planning you can make it so the size of text or other elements scales relative to everything else on the page.

There is a standard CSS way to make elements natively adjust to viewport-size, we should leverage it.
The proposed solution utilizes the calculation: calc(var(--windowWidth) / var(--designWidth)) for zooming the body element (i.e, for zooming everything that is rendered on the page!).
On inspection, zooming by the ratio between --designWidth and --windowWidth has the effect of proportionaly scaling the design to match with the viewport. But it involves calculating (via js) information already available to css. With ViewportUnits we could leverage this fact. And if we need the scaling to be proportional we can use CSS's aspect-ratio
body{
    width: 100vw; /* set width to always match viewport width*/
    aspect-ratio: 9/16 /* 9/16 is just an example. By setting the aspect-ratio consitent for the underlying design, we force the vertical scaling to remain proportional*/

}

The above CSS deals away with media querys and js calculations, but forces the design to always 'be the same' (but ajusted for vw)
Dabbling as we are in responsive design, we could further leverage viewport-units to construct a design that adjusts responsively, e.g.:
body{
    width: 100vw; /* set width to always match viewport width*/
}
@media and (max-width: 420px){ /*think mobile*/ 
    body{
       height: 150vh; /*some aproppiate ratio for slim screens*/
    }
}
@media and (min-width: 420px){ /*bigger than mobile*/ 
    body{
       height: 100vh; /*full height of screen*/
    }
}

@media and (min-width: 1024px){ /*bigger screens*/ 
    body{
       height: unset;
       aspect-ratio: 9/16 /*the aspect ratio you want to preserve for 'massive' screens*/
    }
}


You could subsequently apply this vw and vh units, or aspect-ractio to children of body to achive a trully responsive design without messing with js.


You got me thinking that javascript is going to be much easier... So i have used jquery, and got a very nice simple solution that works well.

Yes, you need js to dynamically set --width and it's simpler than messing with CSS newest features, but i have to point out that viewport units may be what your looking for in terms of responsivenes. 100vh is the entire viewport width regardless of absolute pixel value width, so if you set your css properly, you shouldn need to mess around with zoom, &c. to achieve a design that adjust to the viewport

@Conrad share your answer, or accept this one. Don't let the question opened, especially when you have more than 400 in reputation please.

My proposed zoom calculation is wrong, its would be simply: zoom: windowWidth/designWidth. If you run your snippet, you can see.

This Fiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/5dkb4u0e/5/

I've edited the answer to use innerwidth, and your new proposed zoom calculation (for posterity) but again, consider using viewport units it's the 'idiomatic' way and it should be simpler than procedurally calculating the viewport width as you're already using media querys.

I can't seem to achieve the results with viewport units. So far the js solution is working, but there is a flicks when you navigate, as the script executes. I feel like a CSS only solution would work better, but it seems a body.zoom value is more compatible.
